# NSDirectoryFileType is deprecated. What's the replacement?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, icons, deprecated

I have an `NSOutlineView` that displays a directory hierarchy (not necessarily local).  I want to display the icon for each item in the list, so I'm using `NSWorkspace`'s `-iconForFileType:` method, since I can't use `-iconForFile:` as the path isn't always local (could be FTP, SFTP etc).

When I use `NSDirectoryFileType` I'm getting warnings that it was deprecated in Snow Leopard.  How else can I go about achieving this task?

Basically I need a non-deprecated way to get the icon for any given file (and for a directory), given only the filename (and whether or not it is a directory), not a full local path.

```
if ([(EDFileStoreItem *)item type] == EDFileStoreItemDirectory) {
    // WARNING: Deprecated in OS X 10.6
    [(EDImageAndTextCell *)cell setIconImage:[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSDirectoryFileType]];
}
```

**UPDATE:** Ok, I figured it out:

```
NSImage *directoryIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameFolder];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSImage *directoryIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameFolder];
```

Only available in Snow Leopard, AFAIK.